# Passing Nested list as variable does not set the value in parent list

Tags: c#, list, nested

Please view the code below

```
public class Page
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Contains> contains { get; set; }
}

public class Contains
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string index {get; set;}
    public List<Contains> contains { get; set; }
}

public class PageMachine
{
    Page Page;
    List<Contains> PageContainer;

    public PageMachine(string type)
    {
        Events = new Dictionary<string, Events>();

        PageContainer = new List<Contains>();

        Page = new Page()
        {
            type = type,
            contains = PageContainer
        };
    }

    public void Add_Container(string rootIndex, string type, string index)
    {

        Contains container = new Contains()
        {
            type = type,
            index = index,
        };

        SetContainer(rootIndex, index, container, Page.contains);  
    }

    private void SetContainer(string rootIndex, string index, Contains newContainer, List<Contains> containers)
    {
        if(containers == null)
        {
            containers = new List<Contains>();
            containers.Add(newContainer);
        }
        else if(containers.Count == 0)
        {
            containers.Add(newContainer);
        }
        else if(!containers.Exists(x => x.index == rootIndex))
        {
            containers.Add(newContainer);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var container in containers)
            {
                if (container.index == rootIndex)
                {
                    SetContainer(index, index, newContainer, container.contains);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Implementation

```
PageMachine page = new PageMachine("My Page");
page.Add_Container("0", "Parent 1", "0");
page.Add_Container("0", "Child 1 of Perant 1", "0.0");
```

The idea behind this is to create container list for a page, and each container can contain a list of more child containers. The index property on the Contains is used as a mapping, parent `0` and its child is `0.0` and its child will be `0.0.0`.

The problem i am facing is that when the recursive `SetContainer` is called and the `container.contains` is passed in the method, the Page object does not reflect that the List was updated.

I have found it very difficult to explain my problem and will clarify if there are questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason is in

```
if(containers == null)
{
    containers = new List<Contains>();
    containers.Add(newContainer);
}
```

You're creating a new `List` but this is not pointed by the reference you think because, when passing an argument by reference (as `container.contains` in `SetContainer`), the reference is **copied**.

I'll try to illustrate it. The second time `SetContainer` is called (recursively), `container.contains` points to null.

```
container.contains --> null
```

This argument is passed by reference to `SetContainer`. This means that the reference is **copied**. This copied reference is the one used inside `SerContainer`, in other words the parameter `containers`.

```
container.contains --> null
                       ^
                       |
containers ------------+
```

Now, since `containers` is null, the first `if` statement is true and a new `List` is created, and containers points to that.

```
container.contains --> null

containers ----------> newList
```

When you add the item, this is added correctly to the newList, but `container.contains` is not pointing to it. This is why, when `SetContainer` returns, nothing has changed. I hope I've been clear.

One way to fix this is to make sure to create the list before calling `SetContainer`, for instance changing the `if` statement inside the `for` loop to

```
if (container.index == rootIndex)
{
    if(container.contains == null)
        container.contains = new List<Contains>();

    SetContainer(index, index, newContainer, container.contains);
}
```

and of course deleting `containers = new List<Contains>();` from the first `if` statement. From a quick test, it seems to work for me.

Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks mate, you are very clear in your response! Much Appreciated!